# how to remove spaces in and of text field

Tags: sql, oracle, string, oracle10g

I have field X that contains text with spaces in the end of the text.

How I can remove them?

I need it in any SQL query for oracle 10g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select trim(COLUMN_NAME) from .......
;
```

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking if you want to only remove trailing spaces then you'd use `RTrim()`. `LTrim()` is leading spaces and `Trim()` is both.